# Axis2 Hierarchy Contexts doesn't start

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to develop a service with application scope on Axis2 server and when I start my service the axis2 server doesn't instance the contexts hierarchy.

Someone can help me to understand why the contexts are not started by Axis2 server?

Here the code of the class:

```
package xxx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ServiceContext;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService;
import org.apache.axis2.service.Lifecycle;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Transportsessionservice implements Lifecycle {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginStrong.class);

  public int loginTablet(String username, String password) throws Exception {

    ServiceContext serviceContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getServiceContext();
    String ip = (String)MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getProperty("REMOTE_ADDR");
    log.info("SERVICE start ["+ip+"]");

    if(serviceContext.getProperty("COUNT") == null) {
      serviceContext.setProperty("COUNT", 1);
    } else {
      int c = (Integer)serviceContext.getProperty("COUNT");
      serviceContext.setProperty("COUNT", c++);
    }
    log.info("COUNT = " + serviceContext.getProperty("COUNT"));
  }

  @Override
  public void init(ServiceContext serviceContext) {
    log.info("init");
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy(ServiceContext serviceContext) {
    log.info("destroy");
  }

}
```

Below the service.xml file that I'm using:

```
<serviceGroup>
<service name="Transportsessionservice" scope="application">
    <Description>This is a sample service to test transport scope</Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">xxx.Transportsessionservice</parameter>
</service>
</serviceGroup>
```

And finally the output of the apache tomcat:

```
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\margheritti.luigi\Oracle\obiee11g\oraMiddle\Oracle_BI1\products\Essbase\EssbaseServer\bin;C:\Users\margheritti.luigi\Oracle\obiee11g\oraMiddle\Oracle_BI1\bin;C:\Users\margheritti.luigi\Oracle\obiee11g\oraMiddle\Oracle_BI1\opmn\bin;C:\Users\margheritti.luigi\Oracle\obiee11g\oraMiddle\Oracle_BI1\opmn\lib;C:\Users\margheritti.luigi\Oracle\obiee11g\oraMiddle\Oracle_BI1\perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam SDK 11.0\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam SDK 11.0\Bin;C:\blp\Api\dde;C:\blp\Api;.
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyBusiness_v2' did not find a matching property.
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 302 ms
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
23-ott-2012 14.26.19 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.1 - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.1.mar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: Transportsessionservice - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/services/Transportsessionservice/
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/C:/Data/Personal/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyBusiness_v2/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[INFO] init
[WARN] No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml file!
23-ott-2012 14.26.20 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
23-ott-2012 14.26.20 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
23-ott-2012 14.26.20 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/12  config=null
23-ott-2012 14.26.20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1042 ms
```

Please help me to find a solution to active the hierarchy of the contexts.

Answer (score 0):

> Please update your axis2.xml file!  include this

```
      <parameter name="manageTransportSession" locked="false">true</parameter>
```

Comment: where can i find this axis2.xml file from? pls reply

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: Please check this link of github with project hierarchy

Comment: https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/master/axis2-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml

Comment: and check the above as mentioned to true